# If object in array is found, increment value inside, if not push to array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to perform an updateOne() query on my db where if an object within an array in the doc, has an _id that matches some value, increment a value within that document, but if there are no matches with that _id, push a new object to the array

Reduced schema:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String
    counting: [{
        _id: String
        score: Number
    }]    
})
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

And the attempted, not working, query with example _id's:

```js
const userId:     '5'
const countingId: '2'

await UserModel.updateOne(
    { _id: userId},
    { counting: {
        $cond: { 
            if: { $in: [ countingId, '_id' ] },
            then: { $inc: { 'score': 1 } },
            else: { $push: { _id: countingId, score: 1 } }
        }
    } }
)
```

If the current db contains a doc of:

```js
{
    _id: 5,
    counting: {
        _id: 2,
        score: 50
    }
}
```

When the query is done, the doc becomes:

```js
{
    _id: 5,
    counting: {
        score: 0
    }
}
```

So when the query matches the countingId, it removes the 'counting._id' field and sets the score to 0

If there are no matches with countingId, nothing happens

Can someone please help me understand why this query doesn't work and how I might go about fixing it

Comment: i think this is that you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/75598236/9267467

Comment: @TobokSitanggang The post has been removed! agh

Comment: is nothing wrong if you do query twice anyway. one to find the `find({ _id: userId, 'counting._id': countingId})`. then you could use the conditional update using `update`.
  `if(true) { use $inc} else { use $push}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to put it into a single query so I've just split it into two separate queries with an if statement

```js
if ( await User.findOne({ _id: userId, 'counting._id': countingId }) ) {
    await User.updateOne(
        { _id: userId, 'counting._id': countingId },
        { $inc: { 'counting.$.score': 1 } }
);} else {
    await User.updateOne(
        { _id: userId },
        { $push: { counting: { _id: countingId, score: 1 } } },
        { upsert: true }
)};
```